# Is there any way to map MySql TIMESTAMP to java.lang.Long?

Tags: java, mysql, jpa, spring-data-jpa, spring-data

So I have this object saved to the database with one property being `dateCreated` which is, of course, saved as MySQL timestamp. But while sending the data to the client, I want to be in milliseconds. Right now, I've mapped it to the `Date` object and converting it to milliseconds further. But I thought, what if I could map my POJO in such a way that it retrieves values in milliseconds. Here is what I've tried.

OmsJob:

```java
@Entity
@EntityListeners(PreventAnyUpdate.class)
@ConfigurationProperties("omsjob")
@Table(name = "OMSJob")
public class OmsJob {

    @Id
    @NotNull
    @Column(name = "jobId")
    private String id;

    @NotNull
    private Long dateCreated; // If I map this property to Date, it works fine

}
```

I thought I'll add a custom converter that'll convert `java.util.Date` or `java.sql.Date` to milliseconds. But it isn't working:

```java
@Component
@ConfigurationPropertiesBinding
public class DateConverter implements Converter<Date, Long> {

    @Override
    public Long convert(Date date) {
        return date.getTime();
    }
}
```

The error I am getting is pretty obvious but is there any way to achieve what I am trying to?

```sh
ERROR 229770 --- [           main] o.h.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper   : Unsupported conversion from TIMESTAMP to java.lang.Long
```

Comment: Why would you want to do that? You should map it to `java.time.LocalDateTime` - how you send that data to the client is independent of the representation in your Java code.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name No, not `LocalDateTime`. The `TIMESTAMP` type in MySQL is akin to the SQL-standard type `TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE`, being framed with an offset-from-UTC of zero. So the equivalent type in Java would be `Instant` or `OffsetDateTime`. The JDBC 4.2 spec requires all JDBC drivers to support `OffsetDateTime` but not `Instant` (oddly).

Comment: @BasilBourque: thanks, I didn't know that. according to the SQL standard `timestamp` is equivalent to `timestamp without time zone` - but then it might have been silly to assume that MySQL cares for that to begin with.

Comment: Be aware that your approach involves data-loss. The [`TIMESTAMP`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/datetime.html) type resolves to microseconds, finer than the milliseconds you are planning.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name No, not the SQL standard. I was saying that MySQL defines its `TIMESTAMP` values with an offset-from-UTC of zero hours-minutes-seconds. That makes the MySQL type similar to the SQL standard’s type `TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE`. The SQL standard does not speak to any implementations such as MySQL.

Comment: @BasilBourque: what I meant was. `timestamp` in the standard refers to a data type _without_ a time zone and I just assumed that MySQL would honor that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An attribute won't know about its converter until you declare it. Do it as follows:

```
@NotNull
@Convert (converter = DateConverter.class)
private Long dateCreated;
```

Also, change the converter as follows:

```
public class DateConverter implements AttributeConverter<Date, Long> {

    @Override
    public Date convertToDatabaseColumn(Long millis) {
        retrun new Date(millis);
    }

    @Override
    public Long convertToEntityAttribute(Date date) {
        return date.getTime();
    }
}
```